# When Managed Bean creates and property of the beans creates?

Tags: java, jsf, ajax4jsf

In our application we use jsf,we have
to redirect the user to home page
 after their session will be expired.For that i need a  path of the home page which i kept in my logout managed bean as a managed bean property.But after session expired if i try to access that it  will arise null pointer exception(managed bean becomes null).Then
i have decide to try alternative (i.e)create logout class manually and try to access the property, at that time the property which i wants to access is become null.How can i access
that property?
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because i need to get the home page path as a dynamic one.Its not to be hot coded.So only i wants to keep as a managed property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the previous answer:

You could use (in web.xml)

```
<error-page>
<exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
<location>viewexpired.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Or Context Parameters instead of Session Attributes. See:

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html
- http://safebox.guisho.com/jsf-how-to-get-webxml-parameters

Or use (in faces-context.xml)

```
<managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
```

for your bean, so it will stay independent from the session.

Answer (score 1):

Correct way of doing this is declaring exception handler factory in faces-config.xml, then implementing the factory by subclassing  `javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory`, and then overriding `handle()` method in your implementation of `javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper`.
There you should analyze the exception for the `ViewExpiredException` class and redirect to your view expired page in that case.

Comment: Hi Ivanov,We have used the same in our applications.But the problem is in only redirection to the error page.My application redirects to the error page.But the page is not loaded.

Comment: By adding the emptysessionPath=true in server.xml i can get its works.